# 'Object Expected' Javascript error in IE8 when using prototype.js

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, prototypejs, object-expected

```
function icPageInit()
{
    $("icImgDiv" + icAlternate()).setOpacity(0);
    return true;
}
window.onload = icPageInit;
```

This piece of Javascript code works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but fails with the error 'Object Expected' in Internet Explorer 8. IE8 says the error occurs on line 3 of the above code.

Does anyone know why this is happening, and/or how to get it working?

Comment: Which version of Prototype? I believe the latest version has IE8 compatibility fixes.

Comment: You need the 1.6.1 release candidate for IE8 support - it was added in RC2, current is RC3.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Figured it out.

Turns out Internet Explorer chokes if you use anything other than `"javascript"` in the `language` attribute of the `script` tag.

I was using version numbers appended onto `javascript` in the `language` attribute, which was causing IE not to load `prototype.js`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that this: *$("icImgDiv" + icAlternate())* returns a reference to an element? If so, have you tried using Microsoft Script Debugger / Visual Studio to debug when and where the exception is raised?

Answer (score 2):

Also check that the script tag's type is "text/javascript". I had this error in IE8, and fixed it by changing the type= part of the script tag from "application/javascript" to "text/javascript".